# cordovaでバックグラウンド動作対応のアプリは作れますか？

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova

monacaで目覚ましアプリを作ろうと思ったのですが、バックグラウンド動作非対応でした。
元になっているcordovaなら可能だったりしますか？
また、下記のどの仕様なら作成可能でしょうか？

Android or iPhoneのいずれかで
1.マルチタスク上にアプリがいる際に指定の時間になったら目覚ましが再生
2.完全にアプリを切っている状態で指定の時間になったら目覚ましが再生

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/32770

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer

こちらのプラグインを使えば、

> 2.完全にアプリを切っている状態で指定の時間になったら目覚ましが再生

を実現可能と思われます。

monacaの有料プランであれば、任意のプラグインがインストール可能だったと記憶しています。
無料プランであれば、cordovaプロジェクトに移行して、このプラグインをインストールしましょう。